# JSTree with Datatables

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables, jstree

I have two columns on a page, with a checkbox jstree on the left and a table using datatables on the right. The table rows and tree are all loaded at startup.

I would like to show a row when the node is selected on the tree and hide the row when its unchecked and I'm using a class for this. I am having problems with looping though all the rows in a datatables and setting a class, so I can filter it. This is the code I'm using below, but its not working. I can't get any id for the table row.

```
table.rows().iterator( 'row', function ( context, index ) {
                var tableNode = $(this.row(index).node());
                tableNode.removeClass('VisibleRow').removeClass('HiddenRow').addClass('HiddenRow');
            var id = tableNode.id;
            var treeNode = data.instance.get_node(id);

            if(treeNode != undefined){
                var currentId = '#row-' + node.id;
                var rowInTable =  table.row(currentId).node();
                $(rowInTable).removeClass("HiddenRow");
                $(rowInTable).addClass("VisibleRow");
            }

});
```

Let me know if there are better ways to do this.

Comment: Did you solve your problem?

Comment: thanks..this worked. I was able to modify and it worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you can do it with the snippet below. The rows iteration is jQuery based, there is no DataTables-specific logic there.

Also check demo - [Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ermakovnikolay/cf7tata9/)

```
var $tableRows = $('#yourTableId').find('tr');

$('#yourTreeContainer').on('select_node.jstree', function(e, data) {

    $tableRows.each(function() {
        if (this.id === '#row-' + data.node.id) {
            $(this).removeClass('HiddenRow');
        } else {
            $(this).addClass('HiddenRow');
        }
    });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

I created same with some changes and it works fine, but even with hidden row I don't want datatable showing empty pages. Any advice, please?

this my code

```
$('#jstree')
  .jstree({
    core: {
      data: treeData
    },
    checkbox: {       
      three_state : false, // to avoid that fact that checking a node also check others
      whole_node : false,  // to avoid checking the box just clicking the node 
      tie_selection : false // for checking without selecting and selecting without checking
    },
    "plugins" : ["checkbox","conditionalselect"]
  })
  .on("check_node.jstree uncheck_node.jstree", function(e, data) {

   $tableRows.each(function(){  

   //$(this).addClass('HiddenRow'); //should not be there

     if( this.id === data.node.id ) {
       if(data.node.state.checked ){
         //alert("removeClass");
         $(this).removeClass('HiddenRow');
       }else{
         //alert("addClass");
         $(this).addClass('HiddenRow');
       };
     }else{

     }
   })
})
```

This is the link http://jsfiddle.net/cf7tata9/56/#&togetherjs=jqPTfx3gpk